# Is it possible to define a function name with #define?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WAITINGFUNC void waitingfor

WAITINGFUNC(double seconds)
{
    sleep(seconds);
}

void main()
{
    WAITINGFUNC(3);
}
```

Is it possible to give a function name like that? About making the code readable stuff for anybody.

Also, I got this error: `expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant`.

Comment: Don't hide stuff behind macros if your goals is readability. People reading C code don't have issues parsing normal function declarations.

Comment: This is doing the opposite of making anything readable for anybody. To define your function just use void waitingfor(double seconds); Also simply wrapping a function with another function with no other logic used is a detriment to readability.

Comment: `WAITINGFUNC(3);` expands to `void waitingfor(3);`. You have to remove that `void`...

Comment: Hiding important details such as the return type of a function *hinders* readability.

Answer (score 5):

In your code `WAITINGFUNC` expands to `void waitingfor`. This is as expected when you're declaring a function, but isn't when you're calling it. So, in `main` function, you essentially have this:

```
void main()
{
    void waitingfor(3);
}
```

Aside from the fact that `main` *must* return `int`, not `void`, `void waitingfor(3);` is a syntax error as it doesn't mean anything. Using MACROS for function declarations isn't a bright idea and it doesn't improve the code readability in any meaningful way. You'd better stick to the normal function declaration as almost all C programmers are very good at reading and understanding most function declarations anyway.